# Ebook resources for math learning (10th-12th grade)

Tags: self-learning, online-resources

After searching the site, i found some questions like mine, but none fits my case.

I am a 11th grade student, and i have an ebook reader(kindle). I would like to know where can i find(free) content about intermediate math learning, so i could spend some spare time (when away from the computer) studying.

The ideal is .mobi's, but .pdf's are also fine.

I already looked MIT OCW pdf's, but i don't understand a lot, and i don't know from where should i start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an awesome website made by a free foundation.
The site of the CK-12 foundation (http://www.ck12.org) seems to have lots of content, ordered by section.

All of the content is free licensed under CC licenses, and has an option to download for Kindle/iPad or PDF for offline viewing.

While sites like the gutemberg project and MIT OCW have lots of content, but mostly they're incomprehensible for a eleventh grade student, this site seems to be a simplification, and everything is very acessible to read.

I'll give it a try for a few days, then i'll leave some feedback.
I still have hope to find more resources. Every answer helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

try Project Gutenberg at:

http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/subjects/search/?query=math

Also, search by subject.

You can get all sorts of books including classics and the price is just great!

HTH